# EpPlus Sum Calculation returns a different result

Tags: c#, sum, epplus

I am trying to use SUM() to calculate and retrieve values with EpPlus for verification. However, Excel is showing 586,615.99, While EpPlus seems to show 586,615.86 (Cell "S6123") Am I missing something? 
The first line of code works great, the second, not so much. Both numbers match in Excel. Attached, please find an example spreadsheet with the problem. Below is the code used to retrieve the results. Thank you.

```
using (ExcelPackage excel = new ExcelPackage(fi))
    {
    excel.Workbook.CalcMode = ExcelCalcMode.Automatic;
    excel.Workbook.Calculate();
    decimal dSummaryTotal ;
    decimal dDetailsTotal ;

    //Correct
    dSummaryTotal = Convert.ToDecimal(excel.Workbook.Worksheets[2].Cells["C29"].Text); //586,615.99
    //InCorrect
    dDetailsTotal = Convert.ToDecimal(excel.Workbook.Worksheets[3].Cells["S6123"].Text); // 586,615.86
    }
```

[Sample Spreadsheet](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12AWTXsgft7grTYxXviKhWEp04hDQ076B/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I am not exactly sure, but I have feeling it might have to do with the precision when using the Convert.ToDecimal method. Have you tried to extract the values, using the Value property instead and (maybe) then you don't need the conversion? Like so: `dSummaryTotal = excel.Workbook.Worksheets[2].Cells["C29"].Value;`  `dDetailsTotal = excel.Workbook.Worksheets[3].Cells["S6123"].Value;`

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, I have tried using other variable types, double, float,etc. I have also tried retrieving the value from other variables within the cell class, such as value(586,615.862666666) to no avail.  I just can't seem to get the displayed .99 value.. ugh.